# intellij idea, maven spring-boot:run doesn:'t stop

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I can run my spring boot application with this command in maven

```
spring-boot:run
```

but I can not stop the application from the toolbar on intellij idea. I have no idea why this is happing.

I'm using Openjdk-14 I also try this with openjdk-11 but not working too.

After I click the stop button terminal log this

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51890', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Why not starting your Spring Boot app from your IDE?

Comment: @khmarbaise because I'm using community version.

Comment: See detailed answer this pictures: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802054/13213920

Answer (score 0):

When the terminal to start the application intelliJ does not know about the running state. You will have to configure the run configuration under "Run" => "Edit configuration". Then you can start the application with the IDE

Comment: I'm already starting the application like you say. but I can't stop it.

Comment: Are you using the "Maven" template or like Spring boot?