# My Spring-Boot app won't stop running in IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a Spring-Boot app which I start-up in IntelliJ this way:

[image]

However when I want to stop this app by clicking:

[image]

It just keeps spinning forever and I can't successfully start the app again:

[image]

The only thing that helps is restarting my machine.
Any advice on how to kill that running instance locally without having to restart my machine?

Comment: That process will stop if you kill the JVM.  You don't need to restart your machine.  IntelliJ can run it without using the Maven plug in.  Run it as a Spring Boot app.

Answer (score 1):

What is the Operational System that you are using? I would recommend you to end the process on your Task Manager.

- MacOS: It can be done pressing [Cmd] + [Alt] + [Esc]
- Windows: It can be done pressing [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Delete]
- Linux: Search the app called System Monitor

Comment: I use Win10 and yes I can use [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Delete] but then I need to hunt for the correct Java process to kill which at any given time I have 5-7.Why doesn't IntelliJ kill the proper one when I press then red square icon?

Answer (score 0):

The Idea knows nothing about this launch (process).
Cause: this application was launched from the command line, but outside the Idea container.
This launch is equivalent to launching from CMD.
Solution:

1. Find the PID of the process of your spring application.
   [image]

---

2.Command for use:
cmd:  taskkill /F /PID 
bash: taskkill //F //PID 
[image]

---

3. Check the result.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because Intellij is not directly running your application. Try to check in settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Maven->Runner whether "Delegate IDE build/run action to Maven" is checked. Uncheck it and try again.